# Notacion de paso de parametros en python

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola el siguiente fragmento de codigo pertenece a tkinter python, sin embargo me encuentro con una notacion de paso de parametros que no encuentro en la documentación.Podeis ofrecerme ayuda.La sintaxis es la siguiente config(text=format % args) y el contexto es el siguiente.

```
class StatusBar(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.label = Label(self, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        self.label.pack(fill=X)

    def set(self, format, *args):
        self.label.config(text=format % args)
        self.label.update_idletasks()

    def clear(self):
        self.label.config(text="")
        self.label.update_idletasks()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método  `set` solo  usa el viejo método de formateo de cadenas mediante `%` para asignar la cadena a mostrar por el `Label`, el cual sigue la sintaxis:

> formato % valores

dónde `formato` es la cadena a formatear, la cual contiene uno o más especificadores a sustituir que son identificados mediante el carácter `"%"` al inicio del mismo, mientras que `valores` pueden ser un solo elemento o una tupla de elementos con el mismo número de items especificados en el formato o bien un objeto *mapping*, como un diccionario.
Puedes ver una explicación mucho más pormenorizada en la documentación:

- [String formating operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

Algunos ejemplos:

```
>>> "Un rectángulo de %.2f cm de ancho por %.2f cm de alto" % (4.2555, 8.2146)
'Un rectángulo de 4.26 cm de ancho por 8.21 cm de alto'

>>> "Stack Overlow en %s" % "español" 
'Stack Overlow en español'

>>> '%(nombre)s tiene %(edad)d años' % {"nombre": "Pedro", "edad": 27}
'Pedro tiene 27 años'
```

Actualmente este método sigue disponible pero se considera anticuado en favor de `str.format` y de los [literales de cadena formateados](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (Python >= 3.6) ambos considerablemente más flexibles.

Tienes también una extensa explicación con ejemplos incluidos de esto en la documentación:

- [Format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

En tu caso el método espera una cadena a formatear como primer argumento y un número indeterminado de argumentos posicionales que se corresponderán exactamente con los valores a substituir en la cadena. Un ejemplo reproducible para que lo puedas ver con algunos ejemplos diferentes de llamada al método:

```
import tkinter as tk


class StatusBar(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, bd=1, relief=tk.SUNKEN, anchor=tk.W)
        self.label.pack(fill=tk.X)

    def set_string(self, format_, *args):
        self.label.config(text=format_ % args)
        self.label.update_idletasks()

    def clear(self):
        self.label.config(text="")
        self.label.update_idletasks()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x200")

    f1 = StatusBar(root)
    f1.set_string("%.2f, %.2f", 4.257, 2.356)
    f1.pack(fill=tk.X)

    f2 = StatusBar(root)
    f2.set_string("%s, %s y %s", "Pedro", "Laura", "Marco")
    f2.pack(fill=tk.X)

    f3 = StatusBar(root)
    f3.set_string("%30s", "Stack Overflow")
    f3.pack(fill=tk.X)

    f4 = StatusBar(root)
    a = 2
    b = 3
    r = 6
    op = "x"
    f4.set_string("%d %s %d = %d", a, op, b, r)
    f4.pack(fill=tk.X)

    root.mainloop()
```

> **Nota:** debe evitarse el uso de `set` y `format` como nombres para nuestros métodos o variables, ambos son funciones preconstruidas en Python, las cuales solapamos con ello, aparte de poder ser confuso.

`*args` es usado para enviar un número indeterminado de argumentos ("non-keywords") a la función, de forma que al final `args` será una tupla que contendrá los valores de esos argumentos y cuya longitud solo se conoce en tiempo de ejecución cuando se llama la función. Esto es así, porque el número de argumentos de la función depende del número de especificadores a sustituir en la cadena pasada como primer argumento, como se observa ene le ejemplo anterior.